# Hi! Need help for writing a predicate logic statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

Question to write three predicate logic statements according to the claim below:

1. All tigers are liked by some lion. My answer: ∀x, ∃y s.t Tiger(x) ^ Lion(y) -> Likes(x, y)
2. No lion likes a herbivore. My answer: ∀x, Lion(x) -> ~ Likes(herbivore)
3. Therefore, no tiger is a herbivore. My answer: ∀x, Tiger(x) ^ ~Herbivore(x)

Firstly, I'm not sure if I'm allowed to create a "Likes()" function, and secondly not sure if "Likes(herbivore)" is allowed as well

I'm really bad at discrete math so hoping if someone could tell me if I'm wrong anywhere :)

Could I also get help in writing a proof for the claim? Thank you!

If it's not too much trouble, solutions with explanations would be great as I always find it hard to understand without solutions for comparison :/

Comment: $\text {Likes}(x,y)$ is not a function but a binary predicate. Thus, you have to be consistent and use it always with two arguments.

Comment: And $\text{Herb}(x)$ is a unary predicate; thus you cannot use it in the argument place of another predicate.

Comment: 3) $∀x (\text {Tiger}(x) \to \lnot \text {Herbivore}(x))$ that is equiv to : $\lnot \exists x (\text {Tiger}(x) \land \text {Herbivore}(x))$.

Comment: 2) $∀x ∀y (\text{Lion}(x) \land \text {Herbivore}(y) \to \lnot \text {Likes}(x,y))$.

Comment: If $\text{Likes}(x,y)$ expresses the fact that $x$ likes $y$, then to express the fact $x$ is liked by $y$ you have to write $\text {Likes}(y,x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. All tigers are liked by some lion. My answer: $∀x, ∃y: Tiger(x) \land Lion(y)\implies Likes(x, y)$

Wrong. The original sentence, "All tigers are liked by some lion", would be false in a world where no lions existed. Your formulation of the sentence would also be true in a world where no lions existed, since $Tiger(x)\land Lion(y)$ would always be false. Instead of $\implies$, try writing some other logical operator.

---

> 2. No lion likes a herbivore. My answer: $∀x, Lion(x)\implies\neg Likes(herbivore)$

This is not OK, because the predicate $Likes$ is a predicate with two arguments, not just one. Also, herbivore is a predicate, so it should be $Likes(\_\_, herbivore(\_))$ with something written on the lines.

---

> Therefore, no tiger is a herbivore. My answer: $∀x, Tiger(x) \land \neg Herbivore(x)$

Your answer reads as follows:

> All things are tigers and not herbivores.

I trust you understand this is different from the intended meaning.

Comment: hi! thanks for the reply, actually, is it possible for you to show me how I should actually solve this?

Comment: @LostChild I told you what you did wrong, and gave you some hints on how to proceed. Now it's your turn to re-try solving the problems.

Comment: 1. ∀,∃ s.t Tiger(x) -> Lion(y) ^ Likes(y, x)
2. ∀,∀, (Lion(x) ^ Herbivore(x)) -> ~ Likes(x, y)
3. ∀, Tiger(x) -> ~ Herbivore(x)
I managed to get the answers yea, thanks!

Comment: @LostChild Looks good, well done!